# When will vessel start heating when ice inside is heated?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, phase-transition

If we have an aluminium vessel containing ice at 0 °C and we supply heat to it.
Will the ice first melt completely and then the temperature of the whole system increases or will the vessel's temperature increase simultaneously as the ice is melting?

Comment: If you are directly heating ice without giving vessel any heat, the vessel will heat only after complete phase transition.

Comment: We are providing heat to the whole system

Comment: Then of course the vessel has started to heat initially. But some of the heat is going to melt ice. Overall, the heat transfer rate to ice is lower than the heat gain rate of metal, so the metal will increase temperature. That's what happens when you boil ice. The temperature of system starts increasing the moment you start heating.

Answer (score 2):

The temperature of *the surface* of the melting ice will be a constant 0C, but temperature will not be evenly distributed throughout the solid mass of ice or the melt water or the metal pan. It takes time for heat to flow, and the faster you supply it, the less even the distribution of temperature will be.